# Click a marker on the map and direct a position inside in RecycleView

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want that by clicking on a marker on the map, it directs me to a position inside in RecycleView.
I already have the markers on the map, each of them has a name that was retrieved from Firebase and was placed as a title in MarkerOptions.
What does it take to click on a bookmark with an "alpha" title open and display a position where there is also the "alpha" title that is inside a RecycleView?

Code RecycleView:

```
public class ShowImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //recyclerview object
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //adapter object
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //database reference
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    //progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //list to hold all the uploaded images
    private List<Upload> uploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        uploads = new ArrayList<>();

        //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

        //adding an event listener to fetch values
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //dismissing the progress dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //iterating through all the values in database
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    uploads.add(upload);
                }
                //creating adapter
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);

                //adding adapter to recyclerview
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Code Upload.class:

```
public class Upload{

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String local;
    public String url;
    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;

    // Default constructor required for calls to
    // DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    public Upload() {
    }

    public Upload(String name, String description,String local,String latitude, String longitude, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.local = local;
        this.url= url;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude= longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Code Map:

```
ref.child("uploads").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotsChat =  dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                while (dataSnapshotsChat.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotsChat.next();
                    String latitudeL = dataSnapshotChild.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                    String longitudeL = dataSnapshotChild.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                    double latitude1 = Double.parseDouble((latitudeL));
                    double longitude1 = Double.parseDouble(longitudeL);
                    LatLng local = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
                    final String title = dataSnapshotChild.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    final String url = dataSnapshotChild.child("url").getValue().toString();

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(local).title(title));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local, 10));

                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                              //What I put here??
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker), which is better way do realize "place picker", but remember that, according their license, you CAN ONLY save the id of the place, not lat or lon or something else. Also, you have to put "made by Google logo" when you're using Gmaps or places Api.

Comment: another option?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code accordingly

1. Before that you have to get the **Upload model class object position** in the Arraylist for the respective marker.
2. Pass the object position through intent and handle in the *ShowImagesActivity* activity.
3. Use `recyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).`

   `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                 intent = new Intent(this, ShowImagesActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra(ITEM_POSITION, Adapterposition);
                }
   }`

Comment: I updated the codes above, I need to know how to do get the Upload model class object position

Comment: if you maintain same set of data List in both MapActivity and ShowImagesActivity, you can get the object position in which marker you are clicking, so you can pass the position to the next activity through intent.